# How Do I Pass a Context from a Fragment in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

How do you pass a `Context` from a running fragment to another class? I need to get resource data out of it, but for some reason, it appears to be null when I send it through the arguments.

```
class BeatBoxFragment : Fragment() {
...
    var mBeatBox: BeatBox = BeatBox(this.context!!)
...
}
```

I will be using the context of this fragment to access assets from the activity.

```
class BeatBox(context: Context) {
...
    val mAssets: AssetManager = context.getAssets()
...
}
```

The program crashes if I try to call BeatBox with the arguments `this.context!!.` Apparently it is null (according to what my stack trace suggests: android.beatbox.BeatBoxActivity}: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException")

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use requireContext() instend of this.context!!

Comment: In which method do you initialise the `mBeatBox` var? If `this.context` is null, this implies that your fragment has not been attached to an activity yet. You need to initialise it inside a lifecycle override method (e.g. onAttach, onCreate, etc).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **`requireContext()`** which ensure that Fragment is attached and returns a valid non-null Context which we can use without any trouble.

Also you can use `applicationContext` to access `asset` which is not depends on `Activity` Life Cycle